# Silverlight PresentationModel contains a collection of another presentationModel

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have reading Pro Business Application with Silverlight 4 by Chris Anderson,
Regarding the topic EXPOSING DATA FROM THE SERVER: USING WCF RIA SERVICES - Presentation Model Types, it is not so details about a presentation model object contains a property exposing a collection of another presentation model object.

I have the basic idea of how to create a presentationModel,
but how about a PresentationModel contains a collection of another PresentationModel?
Example a ProductPM contains a collection of ProductInventoryPM?
How to write the CRUD code at the Domain Service Class?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several things you need to do in your code.  First, to be able to see the list of product inventory records, you need to select them as part of your GetProducts domain operation:

```
Public Function GetProducts() As IQueryable(Of ProductPM)
    Return From p As Product In Me.ObjectContext.Products.Include("ProductInventories") Select New ProductPM With
                                                                 {.ListPrice = p.ListPrice,
                                                                  .ModifiedDate = p.ModifiedDate,
                                                                  .Name = p.Name,
                                                                  .ProductID = p.ProductID,
                                                                  .ProductNumber = p.ProductNumber,
                                                                  .ProductInventory = From i In p.ProductInventories Select New ProductInventoryPM With
                                                                     {
                                                                        .Quantity = i.Quantity,
                                                                        .ProductID = p.ProductID
                                                                     }
                                                                 }
End Function
```

That will get them showing in the second data grid.

You'll also need to add a constructor to your ProductPM class that initialises the ProductInventory class:

```
Public Sub New()
    ProductInventory = New List(Of ProductInventoryPM)
End Sub
```

The final issue is that the insert domain operations are being called in the wrong order.  As far as I can tell, the best way to handle this is as follows:

1. Create an empty Insert domain operation for the ProductInventoryPM object. No logic is required in it, but the method is required in order for the ProductInventoryPM object to be able to be added to the ProductPM's inventory collection.

   ```
   Public Sub InsertProductInventory(ByVal ProductInventoryPM As ProductInventoryPM)

   End Sub
   ```

   NOTE: If you want to be able to add new inventory records after you've created the product + initial inventory record, then you will need to add logic to this domain operation after all.
2. Insert the inventory objects in the ProductPM's Insert domain operation.  An advantage of this is that there's no need to call SaveChanges.

   ```
   Public Sub InsertProduct(ByVal ProductPM As ProductPM)
       Dim Product As New Product
       Product.Name = ProductPM.Name
       Product.ProductNumber = ProductPM.ProductNumber
       Product.ListPrice = ProductPM.ListPrice
       Product.SellStartDate = DateTime.Now
       Product.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
       Product.SafetyStockLevel = 1000
       Product.ReorderPoint = 700
       Product.StandardCost = 0
       Product.DaysToManufacture = 3
       Product.rowguid = Guid.NewGuid()

       Me.ObjectContext.Products.AddObject(Product)
       Me.ChangeSet.Associate(ProductPM, Product, AddressOf UpdateProductPMKey)

       For Each ProductInventoryPM As ProductInventoryPM In ProductPM.ProductInventory
           Dim productInventory As New ProductInventory

           With productInventory
               .Bin = 1
               .LocationID = 1
               .ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
               .ProductID = ProductInventoryPM.ProductID
               .Quantity = ProductInventoryPM.Quantity
               .Shelf = "A"
           End With

           Product.ProductInventories.Add(productInventory)
           Me.ChangeSet.Associate(ProductInventoryPM, productInventory, AddressOf UpdateProductInventoryKey)
       Next
   End Sub
   ```

Now if you run it, everything should work OK.  Let me know how it goes.

Chris

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you so much. Actually what I have did is same as you, just having the issue with the insert statement. The ProductID is not updated before the InsertProductInventory statement.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the rest of the solution.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm now wondering whether the Product/Inventory relationship would be better marked as a composition, using the Composition attribute.  This forces the insert domain operation calls to be in the right order, and probably makes more sense for this particular scenario.  See this MSDN article for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707346(VS.91).aspx

Comment: Hi Chris, I have read this article, it is quite complex, I'm not so sure how to apply it in this case - Presentation Model. One more question is, lets say I just want to pass my ProductInventory as PM to client, and the Product object remain as EF instead of PM, but the Product must including a collection of ProductInventoryPM, do you have any idea? Meaning if the parent or children is PM, then the related parent or chilren must be in PM too? Then sounds like need to write a lot of CRUD coding.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much. Your solution is working fine, and I have modified the Insert domain operation for the ProductInventoryPM object.

Comment: Hi Chris, One more question is, lets say I just want to pass my ProductInventory as PM to client, and the Product object remain as EF instead of PM, but the Product must including a collection of ProductInventoryPM, do you have any idea? Meaning if the parent or children is PM, then the related parent or chilren must be in PM too? Then sounds like need to write a lot of CRUD coding.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that sort of mixing and matching of entities and presentation models, but I'm sure you can do it.  You should be able to create a partial class that extends the Product entity, and define your collection of ProductInventoryPM objects in that.

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm trying to do it in code behind instead of use DomainDataSource. All the ProductPMs will load in a ListBox named as (ProductListBox), and while the selection changed, another DataGrid (ProductInventoryDataGrid) will display all the related ProductInventories. I'm facing an issue is, I cannot see my new inserted product object in my ProductListBox. My project file is here http://www.mediafire.com/?4u3h7vlwaatr6cc . Everything is working fine with the DomainDataSource at the Home Page, just the problem is using code approach at About Page. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Chris, also another issue is a new ProductPM and ProductInventoryPM insert at the same time. After I have called context.SubmitChanges(), my inserted ProductInventoryPM is disappear, but actually it is already inserted into DB. I have to refresh the whole page to see the inserted ProductInventoryPM. This working fine with using the DomainDataSource, just the problem in code approach. Thanks.

Comment: Which book do you have?  The SL4 or SL5 edition?  In the SL5 edition I discuss the DomainCollectionView in Chapter 6.  Check that out - it should help solve your problems.  If you don't have the SL5 edition, do a web search for the DomainCollectionView class, part of the RIA Services Toolkit.

Comment: Hi Chris, I having an issue while doing it in VB.NET. Argument not specified for parameter 'op' of 'Private Sub OnLoadProductPMListCompleted(op As System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation(Of ProductPM))'.

Comment: collectionViewLoader = New DomainCollectionViewLoader(Of ProductPM)(Function() Me.LoadProductPMList(), Me.OnLoadProductPMListCompleted)

Comment: Private Sub OnLoadProductPMListCompleted(op As LoadOperation(Of ProductPM))

        If op.HasError = True Then


        ElseIf op.IsCanceled = False Then
            CType(Products, EntityList(Of ProductPM)).Source = op.Entities
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: My Project File if you need it : http://www.mediafire.com/?6qadip28buclud5 , please refers to Page1.xaml, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find example for DomainCollectionView in vb.net

Comment: I have posted my new question at here, maybe you could answer at there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902824/silverlight-domaincollectionview-in-vb-net

Comment: I know what was my problem regarding the ProductPM and ProductInventoriesPM insert at the same time, after saved the ProductInventories disappear from the User Interface, because the WCF RIA only update the ProductInventoryID, and the ProductID still remain in 0, it should update the ProductID as well.

Comment: Hi Chris, Now I'm doing on DeleteProductInventoryPM Part and facing some issues. First, I have write a DeleteProductInventory operation without UpdateProductInventory operation, and therefore I cannot delete ProductInventory with the error message "This EntitySet of Type 'AdventureWorks.ProductInventoryPM' does not support the 'Edit' operation." Just wonder I'm deleting ProductInventoryPM but not update it, why it will jump to perform update/edit operation?

Comment: Another issue is, when insert a new ProductInventory without calling context.SaveChanges() first, then delete the new inserted ProductInventory, called context.SaveChanges(), why it will jump to perform InsertProductInventory operation? Could you feel free to provide a sample code of the Delete operation in this case Presentation Model? My project file at here if you needed, http://www.mediafire.com/?b4vkknr883752od , please refers to About.xaml & ProductPMService. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Can I recommend you post your questions to the RIA Services forum here? http://forums.silverlight.net/53.aspx Someone there might be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your input, I have posted my question over the silverlight forum, waiting for approved from the moderator, and I will post the URL of the post over here later as well. Now I'm feeling WCF RIA is diffcult than the WCF service...Feel like want to give up it and continue to use WCF service instead of WCF RIA. Actually I like to use WCF RIA because of the security & authentication are easily to implemented.

Comment: OK, good luck - I'm sure someone there will be able to help you. Regarding plain WCF vs RIA Services, just remember that RIA Services provides a prescribed pattern for interacting with data on the server, and is a layer on top of WCF. There's nothing stopping you from using both together. Also remember that you also have Invoke methods in RIA Services that you can take advantage of to perform specific tasks that you're having trouble with otherwise.

Comment: I have posted my question at here http://forums.silverlight.net/t/253848.aspx/1?WCF+RIA+PRESENTATION+MODEL+CRUD

Answer (score 0):

The CRUD methods for the related types are exactly the same as for the main types.  In the SL4 version of the book, there's a note at the bottom of the section titled "Updating Your Presentation Model Types" which discusses this.  Basically, you just write the Get, Update, Insert, and Delete methods for your ProductInventoryPM models (in the same domain service), and RIA Services will take care of the rest.  Have you experienced any problems doing this?

Comment: Hi Chris, I have tried it, but the problem is I cannot insert both ProductPM and ProductInventoryPM at the same time, an error occurs at the domain service due to the ProductInventoryPM do not have a valid ParentID meaning ProductID, the ProductID of ProductInventoryPM is remain as 0, therefore caused this error.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have write Create and Get statement for the ProductPM & ProductInventoryPM, the association between the ProductPM and ProductInventoryPM. I have 2 DataGrids autogenerated, 1 is for the ProductPM, and another is for the ProductInventoryPM. When I selecting ProductPM, the DataGrid of ProductInventoryPM is displaying no data.

Comment: Ah, OK. I see your problem now.  While it's not an ideal solution, this should work: Call this.ObjectContext.Save() after adding each new Product entity, then set the ProductID returned back from the database on all the related ProductInventoryPM objects.  Then when their Add domain operations are called, they'll have the right ProductID set.  Off the top of my head, that should work.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry for my coding, I'm practice in VB.NET language instead of C#.

Comment: Will answer as another answer, as I can't fit the info into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, it is working fine.

And I have modified the Insert domain operation for the ProductInventoryPM object as below so a new ProductInventory record can be add into an existing Product.

> Public Sub InsertProductInventory(ByVal ProductInventoryPM As ProductInventoryPM)
>
> If ProductInventoryPM.ProductID <> 0 Then
>
> Dim productInventory As New ProductInventory
>   With productInventory
>        .Bin = 1
>        .LocationID = 1
>        .ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
>        .ProductID = ProductInventoryPM.ProductID
>        .Quantity = ProductInventoryPM.Quantity
>        .Shelf = "A"
>   End With
>
> Product.ProductInventories.Add(productInventory)
>   Me.ChangeSet.Associate(ProductInventoryPM, productInventory, AddressOf UpdateProductInventoryKey)
>
> End If
>
> End Sub